# Typescript type of class which extends a known class

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, typescript-typings

I am modeling a data structure in code to create an SDK. I have for example, two "types" of "letter" available. The abstract class `letter` states that a `character` property will always be present.

Further down there will be a function that will take in the `letter` and print the character. The issue is, each class that extends `letter` is its own type. How could this function expect to take in any class which extends `letter`?

```js
abstract class Letter {
  abstract character: string
}

class A extends Letter {
  character = "A"
}

class B extends Letter {
  character = "B"
}

function printLetter(letter: Letter) {
  console.log(letter.character)
}

printLetter(A) // see error
```

Error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Letter'.
  Property 'character' is missing in type 'typeof A' but required in type 'Letter'.(2345)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
abstract class Letter {
  abstract character: string
}

class A extends Letter {
  character = "A"
}

class B extends Letter {
  character = "B"
}

function printLetter(letter: Letter) {
  console.log(letter.character)
}

const aInstance = new A()

printLetter(aInstance)
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I just overlooked that in my simplified test. Glad to know this does actually work this way. Thank you!